# Builder or Factory for creating an instance with another builder

Tags: design-patterns

I have the classes A (client), B, C (Builder), and D (Obj).

If a builder (C) is used to create an instance of D, and I would like to simplify (easier reuse) that process should B be a builder or a factory (or even a director).

Take this example:

```
capabilities = _.extend({}, {
    // Other default capabilities

    'resolution': '1920x1080'
}, capabilities);

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .usingServer('http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub')
    .withCapabilities(capabilities)
    .build();

return driver;
```

C here is clearly the provided builder, and D is the driver.

The real question is what should the wrapping class be? A factory or a builder?

Comment: It's unclear to me what gain is expected from using B. What difficulty does the client have with using the builder C that B is expected to solve?

Comment: It is a convenience wrapper. I have added more code.